# What is the London Weekly Cap impact if one trip taken outside of zone?

Tags: london, tfl

I'm traveling to London in April, and will be heavily traveling on the tube through zone 1 and 2, easily maxing out my weekly cap every week I'm there (w/ new fares this will be 42.70/week).

I plan to take one round-trip visit out to Hampton Court Palace via the Rail (zone 6).
How will this be calculated?

Will I simply get one day capped from zone 1-6 at 15.60? And then the rest of my week via zones 1-2? An additional cost of of ~7.

Or will I get hit with a weekly cap of the zone 1-6 at 78.00 (even thought I only traveled out that far once?); an additional cost of ~35.

Thanks for any help!

Note: I'm keeping the above example fairly simple to help me understand the process.

Comment: Tfl's [Pay as you go caps](https://tfl.gov.uk/fares/find-fares/tube-and-rail-fares/pay-as-you-go-caps) explains it. I don't understand what you mean by "hit with a weekly cap". A cap limits what you will pay. Your "maxing out my weekly cap" suggests you think it means a limit to the journeys you can make.

Comment: If you are travelling once outside the zones you have paid for, why not just pay for that separately?

Answer (score 9):

The way the caps work is that every day, the total amount paid cannot exceed the daily cap for the zones used that day, and then the total amount paid for the week cannot exceed the weekly cap for the zones travelled during that week.

Basically, you only pay the smallest amount you could pay using either individual fares or daily caps or the weekly cap or combinations thereof.

So for each day you stay within zones 1-2 the cap will be £8.50, and for the day you go to Hampton Court Palace it will £15.60 (of course any day you are below the cap you will be only charged the actual fares).

If that week you travel 5 days (4 at 8.50 and one at 15.60) then your total cost will be 4 x 8.50 + 15.60 = 49.60. You don’t hit the weekly cap for zones 1-6, so that cap doesn’t apply.

Even if you travel all 7 days (with only one day in 1-6) you would only pay 66.60, well below the £78 weekly cap for zones 1-6.

Comment: Thank you.  Exactly the answer I was searching for.

Comment: @Ray make sure you click the up arrow to say "thank you" (if you haven't yet), and click the check mark so others know that this has an accepted answer.